# How to assign a unique ID to groups of items in the attribute table in ArcMap?

Tags: python, field-calculator, loop

Using arcmap's field calculator I need to programatically loop through all of the entries in the field and for each name it gets its own unique id.  So names that are the same would get the same number. This is done through model builder.

def NameReclass(name):
    foreach name in species .... etc.

I'm just really confused how to do this without if/elif statements and specifying the string name == 1, etc. because it needs to be an id for each name shown.

Comment: Please include an example containing original and desired output.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is using elif off the table?

Comment: Several softwares have field calculators, so it might be helpful to specify which one. Is there one entry/word per field, or multiple (ie `bird` vs `bird, rodent`)? I believe you'll be wanting to look at either a dictionary or a CASE statement. How many possible words/numbers are there?

Comment: Use 2 lists, one with possible names, second with matching numbers

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Python [setdefault()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.setdefault) method and an [UpdateCursor](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018w00000014000000) to do this.

```
import arcpy

fc = r'C:\temp\your_shapefile.shp'

# create an empty dictionary
convert = {}

# Start an update cursor and add unique ID based on unique string value
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ["species", "code"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[1] = convert.setdefault(row[0], len(convert))
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```

---

To illustrate what is going on behind the scenes, `setdefault()` adds a new key and unique value for every new species it encounters:

> ```
> >>> str2id
> {u'A': 0, u'B': 1, u'C': 2}
> >>>
> ```

---

[image]

Comment: cool, I didn't know about setDefault().  that looks pretty useful.

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
caseList = [ ]

def returnCase(inValue):
   global caseList

   if not inValue in caseList:
      caseList.append(inValue)

   return caseList.index(inValue)
```

http://www.maprantala.com/category/esri/arcmap-esri/field-calculator/